# Termux repository is under maintenance or down

Tags: termux

I tried updating my package list but got the following error.

```
$ pkg update

Checking availability of current mirror: ok           
Ign:1 https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/game-packages-24 games InRelease                            
Ign:2 https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/science-packages-24 science InRelease     
Hit:3 https://termux.mentality.rip/termux-packages-24 stable InRelease                
Err:4 https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/game-packages-24 games Release
  403  Forbidden
Err:5 https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/science-packages-24 science Release
  403  Forbidden
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/game-packages-24 games Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Metadata integrity can't be verified, repository is disabled now.
N: Possible cause: repository is under maintenance or down (wrong sources.list URL?).
E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/science-packages-24 science Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Metadata integrity can't be verified, repository is disabled now.                             
N: Possible cause: repository is under maintenance or down (wrong sources.list URL?).
```

Somebody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Here's a thread on their GitHub on some things you can do https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/2067 "Use Termux application from F-Droid" is one solution.

Comment: The easiest solution would be re-intalling Termux not from Google Play Market/Store  but from other sources like Xiaomi GetApp, Huawei App Gallery, F-Droid or any others.

Answer (score 87):

I also had this problem and I found a way to slove this
Follow these steps :

```
pkg remove game-repo
pkg remove science-repo
pkg update
```

It should work now! :)

Also btw, termux is permanently shutting down bintary hosted repos example :

```
https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/game-packages-24 games InRelease
https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/science-packages-24 science InRelease
```

Comment: Why have they not fixed this yet? I face it even today. Thanks for the solution by the way ♥

Comment: they fixed it but if you install it on play store it will have the problem because they will no longer update the app in play store but they are updating the app in F-Droid if you want to latest and fixed version download from F-Droid not from Play Store

Comment: oh, I didn't know that they stopped updating the PS version. Thanks for the tip. I will download it from F-Droid.

Comment: This does not work unfortunately.

Comment: This answer is awesome but what are game-repo and science-repo do? Because their name looks like something can't affects by that effects on pkg

Comment: @AbdelhamedAbdin Game-repo is for terminal games and I don't really know what science repo is for but I don't think it's very helpful

Comment: 2023, this is still the fix

Answer (score 33):

### Solve Termux repository is under maintenance or down issue

There are mainly 2 options to solve this issue:

#### Solution 1:

If possible, use [Termux from F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.termux/) because there are some [problems with the one from Google Play](https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/2067).

#### Solution 2:

**If you are unable to update or install any package in termux then you can follow the below method to solve this issue.**

1. First of all **type the below command**:

```bash
termux-change-repo
```

2. Now You will see the main repo will be already selected and you just have to **check all ( select all ) gaming as well as the science repo** and then tap on the **OK button**.
3. Now you have to **switch from official repo to Alberto repo** just select the Alberto Repo and **tap on OK Button** and the problem will be sloved.
   *p.s. If Alberto is not working, then try switching to other repos.*

Source : https://www.learntermux.tech/2021/08/termux-repository-under-maintenance.html

Comment: Getting the same thing when switching to Grimler =(

Comment: Use Alberto instead and it will work.

Comment: First option is better as when starting the termux installed from google play it says `this version is outdated and install from f-droid or GitHub`

Answer (score 13):

you can also use

```
termux-change-repo #Note : Do not select Bintray repo or it will not work
```

Or

Remove science and game repo packages to fix it
This problem is caused by the shutdown of bintray repos

the orginal post is from r/Termux